# Is there a map editor thats not a mod

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've played Skyrim on XBox a few times and I really enjoy the scenery.
Skyrim, being a big puzzle on its own, has required me to look up a few things and I sometimes came across posts talking about a map editor.

My questions are:

- Does Skyrim on PC have a map editor that is not a mod?
- Does it come with the standard edition of Skyrim or do I need an  expansion or extra download?
- How much can you really do with a map that you made yourself? (as in play it, do/create quests, etc..)

Any information about the subject is welcome, I don't usually play these kind of games on PC.

Comment: i haven't checked since morrowind, but that answer to the last was: You can do practically anything. For morrowind the tool was the tool the game creators used to make the structure of the game. Only things it didn't do was spell effect creation and  fundamental mechanics (like the skill system), and the artistic parts of creating textures and meshes. It did quests, dialogue, NPCs, buildings, items, monsters. I'm not sure how much has changed since then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Steam version of skyrim comes packaged with the "Creation Kit" for free. It's essentially an easy to use program that you can use to make custom quests, homes, rooms, areas, etc etc using Skyrim's assets.

To install it simply hover over your library on steam, then go to tools. It should be listed under creation kit. Make sure you have Skyrim installed too.

There is a steep learning curve though, and I recommend doing a few tutorials on the wiki: http://www.creationkit.com/Category:Tutorials .

Comment: “Easy-to-use” might be an overstatement. “Easier-to-use-than-modifying-source-code,” I’ll give you, but the CK is a *powerful* tool, designed pretty much exclusively for the benefit of professionals on a tight deadline – lots of desirable features were left out because they either didn’t need it, or they could work around the lack of them faster than they could add them.

Comment: So only the steam version has this Creation Kit?

Comment: @Vahx Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that i bought _Skyrim the legendary edition_ from my local game store (on a disc) and that installing it required me to install steam; and this also gave me access to the creation kit, so you don't necessarily  have to buy it from steam to get access to it.